# SetState not working with spread operator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a language switcher in a React native app, it has the selected language ticked, which is stored in state. However this is not working, any advice appreciated. The code is as below. The `selectedLanguage` is being populated so it knows what needs updating but it's not updating the state object.

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        languages: [
            {
                language: 'Dutch',
                selected: false,
            },
            {
                language: 'English',
                selected: true,
            },
            {
                language: 'French',
                selected: false,
            },
            {
                language: 'German',
                selected: false,
            },
            {
                language: 'Polish',
                selected: false,
            }
        ],

    };
};

changeLanguage(selectedLanguage){

    this.state.languages.map((language) => {
        if(language.language === selectedLanguage){
           this.setState(prevState => ([
               ...prevState.languages, {
                   language: selectedLanguage,
                   selected: true,
               }
           ]));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spread operator isn’t going to deep compare objects in an array. You’ve got to either move from a languages array to a languages object, as in:

```
languages: {
  Dutch: false,
  English: true,
  ...
}
```

Or, you need to copy and replace:

```
changeLanguage(selectedLanguage){

this.state.languages.map((language, index) => {
    if(language.language === selectedLanguage){
       this.setState(prevState => {
           const newLangs = [...prevState.languages];
           newLangs[index].selected = true;
           return newLangs;
       });
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I had tried changing to an object but anyway it's good to know that I can't deep compare with the spread operator. I have got it working now thanks to yours and the other answer.

Comment: I just thought I would mention it. It can be easier to use spread operators with objects (in some ways). Yea - that’s the real take away from what I can tell. Past that, there are a lot ways to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

First need to find out the right object for given `selectedLanguage` from an array.
Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to traverse and update the matched object `selected` prop value with boolean `true` and rest to `false`.

```
const {languages} = this.state;

const updatedLang = languages.map((lang, key) => {
  if (lang.language == selectedLanguage) {
    lang.selected = true;
  } else {
    lang.selected = false;
  }
  return lang;
})
```

Now do `setState`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({languages: updatedLang}));
```

Comment: Thank you very much also for your reply. I have got it working now thanks to yours and the other answer. I was missing the key from the map for starters.